# Cannot read property &#39;split&#39; of undefined error

Tags: node.js, cors, postman

This is my first nodejs postman program. i was checking the CORS configuration. And after completing my code when i tried to run in my postman i got the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;split&#39; of undefined
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at origin (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\src\cors.js:5:34)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:219:13
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at optionsCallback (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:199:9)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at corsMiddleware (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:204:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at urlencodedParser (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at expressInit (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodepro\recipe\server\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
```

origin:

```
function(origin, callback) {
    if(process.env.CORS_WHITELIST.split(' ').indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true);
    } else {
        callback(new Error('Not Allowed By CORS Configuration'));
    }
}
```

I get error saying split is not defined.

I even created a `.env` file for the WHITELIST but I still get the error.

I gave below written code in `.env` file `"CORS_WHITELIST=http://localhost:3000"`.

Comment: please indent your code, its hardly readable

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.CORS_WHITELIST` is probably undefined. Use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module to make sure environment variables are accessible in `process.env`.

`require('dotenv').config()`

By default the path will be root. You can add path if .env file is in a different place.

`require('dotenv').config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars' })`

Comment: Thank you sir. it worked. The solution was as you suggested, i dint give .config().